# creating a simd::float2 from an initializer list

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I can't create a [`simd::float2`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/simd_float2?language=objc) from an initializer list:

```
#include <simd/simd.h>

void f(simd::float2) { }

int main() {
    f({0.0f,0.0f}); // Doesn't work
    f(simd::float2{0.0f,0.0f}); // Works
}
```

The error is:

```
candidate function not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument
      to 'simd::float2' (aka 'simd_float2')
```

Is there a way around this? I'd like to keep as much of my code vector type agnostic as possible.

Comment: overload the function?

Comment: Is the relevant constructor `explicit`?